# Why does the DbContext.Attach set an entity state to EntityState.Modified?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, change-tracking

Why does the `DbContext.Attach` set an entity state to `EntityState.Modified` in the following example?

```
var db = new TestContext();
var book = new Book { 
    BookId = 1, 
    Author = new Author {
        FirstName = "Charles", 
        LastName = "Dickens" 
    } 
};
db.Attach(book); // Book Modified, Author Added - no "store generated key"
```

The example is taken from [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/change-tracker).

According to the `Attach` method description the method:

> Tells EF that the entity already exists in the database, and sets the state of the entity to Unchanged.

So, in the example above I would expect the `Book` to be `Unchanged`, but not `Modified`. Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**

After trying out the code, I figured out that it won`t work at all. That is because we can perform the `Attach` operation only on a set of objects. So, the `db.Attach(book);` should be changed to the `db.Books.Attach(book);`. But still I can not understand what makes the `Attach` method set the state of an entity to `Modified`, but not the `Unchanged`.

Comment: Are you testing in .NET or .NET Core?

Comment: And how are you testing to see that it's `Modified`?

Comment: @GabrielLuci, I just tried it out over [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MhJDGo). To test the state I used the `Console.WriteLine(db.Set.Entry(Entity).State)`.

Comment: @GabrielLuci, actually I am just curious whether or not it is possible at all to have the entity state being `Modified` after the execution of the `Attach` method.

Comment: Well, you are saying it is `Modified`. I'm asking how you know that.

Comment: Its written there... db.Attach(book); // Book Modified, Author Added - no "store generated key"

Comment: (1) The code comment in question is apparently wrong - "Modified"  should be "Unchanged" (2) The link is for EF **Core**. EF Core is different than EF6. EF Core `DbContext` has `Attach` method, EF6 doesn't. Also the behaviors of the methods with the same name can be different (3) The behaviors of some methods like this are/can be different even in different EF Core versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing the behaviour you're describing. I added this code to [your fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MhJDGo):

```
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    var customer = new Customer() {CustomerID = 1};
    context.Customers.Attach(customer);
    var entity = context.Entry(customer);

    Console.WriteLine(entity.State);
}
```

And the output is:

```
Unchanged
```

Just like [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.attach?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) says it would be.

Maybe that comment (`// Book Modified, Author Added - no "store generated key"`) is either a mistake, or describing that they intend to add the author to it. In that case, you would have to set the record to `Modified` before calling `SaveChanges`, or just modify whatever you want to modify *after* you call `Attach`, like this:

```
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    var customer = new Customer() {CustomerID = 1};
    context.Customers.Attach(customer);

    //change something
    customer.Description = "something";

    var entity = context.Entry(customer);
    Console.WriteLine(entity.State);
}
```

That would now show `Modified`.

Comment: you are right but in example they add Author entity to book so it can change main book entity to modified IMO

Comment: If that's really what the author intended, then `Author` should have been modified after calling `Attach`. I updated my answer to explain that.